# How can I get the service reference in a child activity in Android

Tags: android, binding, service, android-intent

How can I get the service reference in a child activity.

Basically I started a service called "A" in activity1, I pass the intent to activity2 and started the activity2. How can I get the reference of my service  "A" in activity2.

code in Activity1:

```
getApplicationContext().bindService(new Intent (this, AndroidUpnpServiceImpl.class), serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

It will start the service and bind the service to serviceConnection

Now I want the reference of same service in activity2

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can simply call bindService in your activity2; services are singletons so another service object will not be spawned but you'll connect to the existing one.

Check the [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/qv-z0HM5afo) regarding this topic.